# Script to get timestamp of when file was deleted

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, last-modified

I need a way to monitor when a file gets deleted off of the disk -- If the file is not deleted by a particular time, we will know that one of our other processes FAILED -- and we can be alerted, etc.

PowerShell is my tool of choice and I know I can check when the file EXISTS using **Test-Path**, however -- I would like to use something like **LastWriteTime** but specifically for *that* file in *that* directory.

Also -- if we can ASSUME that the folder *can* be modified in ANOTHER way (possibly via other unrelated files in the folder) -- I would ideally like to understand if THAT particular file was deleted and WHEN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want recorded *when* a specific file was deleted, you need a `FileSystemWatcher` that monitors the file for deletion and logs the information someplace you can retrieve it later (the eventlog for instance).

Create a new event source (requires admin privileges):

```psh
New-EventLog -Source 'FileMonitor' -LogName 'Application'
```

Then create the actual monitor (code shamelessly stolen from [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b)):

```psh
$folder = 'c:\some\folder'
$file   = 'something.txt'

$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $file -Property @{
         IncludeSubdirectories = $false
         NotifyFilter          = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
       }

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Deleted -SourceIdentifier FileDeleted -Action {
  Write-EventLog -LogName 'Application' -Source 'FileMonitor' -EventId 42 `
    -EntryType 'Information' -Message $Event.TimeGenerated
}
```

The deletion time(s) can then be fetched from the eventlog like this:

```psh
Get-EventLog -LogName 'Application' -Source 'FileMonitor' -InstanceId 42 `
    -After (Get-Date).AddHours(-5) | % { [DateTime]$_.Message }
```

The above will retrieve deletion events that occurred within the last 5 hours.

Unregister watched events like this:

```psh
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FileDeleted
```